# how do i use <redirect/> for redirecting to a different page after login authentication?

Tags: reactjs

I am doing a project on Reactjs and I'm new to it. Its just been few days since i have been working on Reactjs. I want to redirect to a new page after successfull  login authentication. I am using  but its not working, and being new to reactjs i cant figure out where i am going wrong. My redirect condition being if both "valid" and "proceed" = false then it will redirect it to another page. The boolean values for "valid" and "proceed" comes from a http response and its working fine but redirect it not working. The page remains as it is.

My sigin component : SignInForm.js->

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Link, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";

class SignInForm extends Component {
  state = {
    email: "",
    pass: "",
    proceed: false,
    valid: false
  };
  passwordChange = event => {
    this.setState({ pass: event.target.value });
  };

  emailChange = event => {
    this.setState({ email: event.target.value });
  };

  handleOperation = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const user = this.state.email;
    const pwd = this.state.pass;
    console.log(user + "|" + pwd);
    this.setState({
      loading: true
    });
    const data = {
      user,
      pwd
    };
    axios
      .post("https://some end-point where i make my request", data)
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
        this.setState({
          proceed: res.data.proceed,
          valid: res.data.valid
        });

        console.log(
          "res pro= " + res.data.proceed + "| res val=" + res.data.valid
        );
        console.log(
          "state pro=" +
            this.state.proceed +
            "|" +
            "state val = " +
            this.state.valid
        );
        if (!this.state.proceed && !this.state.valid) {
          console.log(" In condition");
          return <Redirect to="/Demo" />;
        }
       })

      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  };

   render() {
    return (
       <div className="FormCenter">
        <form className="FormFields">
          <div className="FormField">
            <label className="FormField__Label" htmlFor="email">
               E-Mail Address
             </label>
             <input
              type="email"
              id="email"
              className="FormField__Input"
              placeholder="Enter your e-mail address"
              name="email"
              onChange={this.emailChange}
            />
          </div>

          <div className="FormField">
            <label className="FormField__Label" htmlFor="password">
              Password
            </label>
            <input
              type="password"
              id="password"
              className="FormField__Input"
              placeholder="Enter your password"
              name="password"
              onChange={this.passwordChange}
            />
          </div>

          <div className="FormField">
            <button
              className="FormField__Button mr-20"
              onClick={this.handleOperation}
            >
              Sign In
            </button>
            <Link to="/" className="FormField__Link">
              Create a new account
            </Link>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default SignInForm;`
```

Demo Component :Demo.js ->

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
class Demo extends Component {
  render() {
    return <h1>THIS IS A DEMO</h1>;
  }
}
export default Demo;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Redirect` in render as it is a component. Also make initial state for `valid` & `proceed` as strings instead of boolean (otherwise it'll always be redirecting, as initial state will be always be `false` for both) and update the redirection condition also to incorporate that.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Link, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";

class SignInForm extends Component {
  state = {
    email: "",
    pass: "",
    proceed: "false",
    valid: "false"
  };
  passwordChange = event => {
    this.setState({ pass: event.target.value });
  };

  emailChange = event => {
    this.setState({ email: event.target.value });
  };

  handleOperation = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const user = this.state.email;
    const pwd = this.state.pass;
    console.log(user + "|" + pwd);
    this.setState({
      loading: true
    });
    const data = {
      user,
      pwd
    };
    axios
      .post("https://some end-point where i make my request", data)
      .then(res => {

        this.setState({
          proceed: res.data.proceed,
          valid: res.data.valid
        });

       })

      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  };

   render() {
      if ( this.state.proceed===false && this.state.valid===false) {
          return <Redirect to="/Demo" />;
      }
      return (
         <div className="FormCenter">
          <form className="FormFields">
            <div className="FormField">
              <label className="FormField__Label" htmlFor="email">
                 E-Mail Address
               </label>
               <input
                type="email"
                id="email"
                className="FormField__Input"
                placeholder="Enter your e-mail address"
                name="email"
                onChange={this.emailChange}
              />
            </div>

            <div className="FormField">
              <label className="FormField__Label" htmlFor="password">
                Password
              </label>
              <input
                type="password"
                id="password"
                className="FormField__Input"
                placeholder="Enter your password"
                name="password"
                onChange={this.passwordChange}
              />
            </div>

            <div className="FormField">
              <button
                className="FormField__Button mr-20"
                onClick={this.handleOperation}
              >
                Sign In
              </button>
              <Link to="/" className="FormField__Link">
                Create a new account
              </Link>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      );
  }
}
export default SignInForm;`
```

Hope this helps ! Happy coding.

Comment: Thanks a lot @HemantParashar. It is redirecting to my Demo.js but there is a little issue, it is just rendered  by replacing the signin component (i.e , email nd passord fields are gone and instead the demo.js rendere there).

Comment: @iamayush Yeah that's expected since you only have `<h1>THIS IS A DEMO</h1>` in your demo file. That's how the router works. It replaces the view with the component you've specified corresponding to the path. Do upvote the answer if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

`Redirect` is a component that needs to be rendered. Also setState is async and so its value may not update immediately.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Link, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";

class SignInForm extends Component {
  state = {
    email: "",
    pass: "",
    proceed: false,
    valid: false
  };
  passwordChange = event => {
    this.setState({ pass: event.target.value });
  };

  emailChange = event => {
    this.setState({ email: event.target.value });
  };

  handleOperation = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const user = this.state.email;
    const pwd = this.state.pass;
    console.log(user + "|" + pwd);
    this.setState({
      loading: true
    });
    const data = {
      user,
      pwd
    };
    axios
      .post("https://some end-point where i make my request", data)
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
        this.setState({
          proceed: res.data.proceed,
          valid: res.data.valid
        });

        console.log(
          "res pro= " + res.data.proceed + "| res val=" + res.data.valid
        );
        console.log(
          "state pro=" +
            this.state.proceed +
            "|" +
            "state val = " +
            this.state.valid
        );
       })

      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  };

   render() {

    if (!this.state.proceed && !this.state.valid) {
        console.log(" In condition");
        return <Redirect to="/Demo" />;
    }

    return (
       <div className="FormCenter">
        <form className="FormFields">
          <div className="FormField">
            <label className="FormField__Label" htmlFor="email">
               E-Mail Address
             </label>
             <input
              type="email"
              id="email"
              className="FormField__Input"
              placeholder="Enter your e-mail address"
              name="email"
              onChange={this.emailChange}
            />
          </div>

          <div className="FormField">
            <label className="FormField__Label" htmlFor="password">
              Password
            </label>
            <input
              type="password"
              id="password"
              className="FormField__Input"
              placeholder="Enter your password"
              name="password"
              onChange={this.passwordChange}
            />
          </div>

          <div className="FormField">
            <button
              className="FormField__Button mr-20"
              onClick={this.handleOperation}
            >
              Sign In
            </button>
            <Link to="/" className="FormField__Link">
              Create a new account
            </Link>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default SignInForm;
```

Comment: Async methods needs to be treated differently ?? If then how can i improve my code.